# Since Windows 10 upgrade,will hang after running for a while, followed by whole home network down, any idea?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

This is the most mysterious thing I've ever seen since I have been using computer... Since I upgraded my windows 7 to windows 10, it was ok at the beginning. However, about a week ago, it begins to hang after running for a while. The horrible thing is my whole home network will be down after that! Including wifi and wired one! I have no idea what is going on.. I tried to uninstall virus scanner but nothing help.

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks!!!!!!